# Alamofire GET request with åäö (special characters), invalid url

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to send an API get request with alamofire, but when i use the following url: [https://stuntmans.evosale.se/admin/api/dräkt](https://stuntmans.evosale.se/admin/api/dr%C3%A4kt) , the special character in "dräkt" is returning an invalid url  as response. How would i go about using special characters with alamofire?

Thanks in advance!

Here is a part of the code:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            .authorization(username: "Username", password: "Password"),
            .accept("application/json")]

        AF.request(https://stuntmans.evosale.se/admin/api/dräkt, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by replacing the characters "åäö" with the corresponding characters they're supposed to represent in url, below is the code:

```
var result = Url
        zip(["å", "ä", "ö"],["%C3%A5", "%C3%A4", "%C3%B6"]).forEach {
            result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: $1, options: .literal)
        }

print (result) // the result
```

Answer (score 1):

You could percent encode the URL with `URLComponents`

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://stuntmans.evosale.se")!
components.path = "/admin/api/dräkt"
guard let url = components.url else { return }

AF.request(url, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there possibly a way to do this without splitting the url? @vadian

Comment: Hey! I actually managed to find a solution to this, the solution was to replace the "åäö" in the string to the corresponding encoding or w/e its called. This is the code :           
    var result = Url
        zip(["å", "ä", "ö"],["%C3%A5", "%C3%A4", "%C3%B6"]).forEach {
            result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: $1, options: .literal)
        }